# Why getting NULL even JSON Array exist in response of jQuery.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Basically response consist of *two* things `JSON Array and isValid(flag)`

I can get flag value successful But it gives the null `var resJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(data.notification);`. I debug my script in chrome console but json response exist in data.

Might be following code and console result help you to understand my problem!

```
function getNotificationById(notificationId) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/GetNotifications/",
        dataType : "json",
        data: {"operation": "getNotificationById", "notificationId": notificationId},

        success:function(data){ 

            var resJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(data.notification);
             //   ^-- here is null  

            if (data.isValid) {
            //    ^-- response is true          
                jQuery.each(resJSON,function(i, value){
                    console.log(value.Body);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Chrome Console Result:

[image: Chrome Console Result]

**Edit**
I have tried following solutions:

```
var resJSON = data.notification;  // Chrome Console return **undefined**
```

Comment: try `var resJSON = data.notification;`. I think you are trying to parse an object instead of string

Comment: Since you have set `dataType: 'json'`, `data.notification` will be an object.. so no need to parse it agaibn

Comment: @Cerlin I have tried it gives "resJSON = undefined," in console

Comment: console log the object and see if the property exists or not. like `console.log(data);` or `console.dir(data);`

Comment: @CerlinBoss I get it .. that was my typo mistake ... I was getting "notificaiton" and calling "notification".. Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.
The data as shown in traces are included in data.notificaiton and not data.notification